# Individual screen is showing instead of a tabhost in android eclipse

Tags: android, eclipse, sharedpreferences, android-tabhost

i am self_learner to android.

I have two screens.The first screen contains one edittext and a button,the edittext is to get the input from the user and button is to call the tabhost's activity which is on the second screen.

During run time, after getting input from the user,it should show the appropriate values **(as per the user's input)** to any one of the tab of a tabhost which is on the second screen.

But here my problem is,its showing the answer on the separate screen,not on the tabhost format.

**NOTE:** In the below code i guess only the problem is on using the shared preference to store and display the data to tabhost.please can any one help me?

Please find code below

**Demo_tabActivity.java**

```
  public class Demo_tabActivity extends Activity 
     {

private static String NAMESPACE = "http://tempuri.org/";
   private static String METHOD_NAME = "FahrenheitToCelsius";
   private static String SOAP_ACTION = "http://tempuri.org/FahrenheitToCelsius";
   private static String URL = "http://www.w3schools.com/webservices/tempconvert.asmx?WSDL";

   Button btnFar;
   EditText txtFar,txtshow;


   @Override
   public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
   {
       super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
       setContentView(R.layout.main);

       txtFar = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText_in);

       btnFar = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button1);
       btnFar.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
       {
       public void onClick(View v)
       {
           String b;

         //Initialize soap request + add parameters
         SoapObject request = new SoapObject(NAMESPACE, METHOD_NAME);       

         //Use this to add parameters
         request.addProperty("Fahrenheit",txtFar.getText().toString());

         //Declare the version of the SOAP request
         SoapSerializationEnvelope envelope = new SoapSerializationEnvelope(SoapEnvelope.VER11);

         envelope.setOutputSoapObject(request);
         envelope.dotNet = true;

         try 
         {   
             HttpTransportSE androidHttpTransport = new HttpTransportSE(URL);

             //this is the actual part that will call the webservice
             androidHttpTransport.call(SOAP_ACTION, envelope);

             // Get the SoapResult from the envelope body.

             SoapPrimitive result = (SoapPrimitive)envelope.getResponse();

             SharedPreferences sharedPreferences;
              sharedPreferences=PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(Demo_tabActivity.this);
             Editor editor = sharedPreferences.edit();
             editor.putString("your", "b");
             editor.commit();

             if(result != null)
             {
                 b=result.toString();
                 Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),Tab_1.class);
                 i.putExtra("goto", b.toString());
                 startActivity(i);
             }
             else
             {
                 Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "oops!..empty",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
             }

           }
         catch (Exception e)
         {
           e.printStackTrace();
           }
         }
       });   

   }
 }
```

**Tab_1.java**

```
   public class Tab_1 extends Activity 
    {
EditText tv;
String result;


     /** Called when the activity is first created. */

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
setContentView(R.layout.tab1);

SharedPreferences sharedPreferences;
sharedPreferences = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(Tab_1.this);
String answer= sharedPreferences.getString("your","");

Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();

if(extras !=null)
{
    result = extras.getString("goto");

}
tv=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText_output);
tv.setText(result);
}
  }
```

Thanks for your precious time!!

Comment: You have to learn on how to use Fragments or activity group(Deprecated).

Comment: Andro Selva Can you please guide me by sending some examples/codes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

okay. let me explain it briefly first.

When you call startActivity() it simply means you are trying to call Activity class. But it doesn't mean that you will be able to have your tab bar in all the screens you navigate to. Because tabs are related to the tabActivity and which means its totally separate from the normal activity. So to have your Tabs visible in all the pages, you have to replace the views thus staying in the same tabActivity.

So the first step is to get the next activity which you want to display  as a view and add it to the tabs. This is what Activity Group is emant to do. Here is a very good example of how to understand ActivityGroup.

[ActivityGroup Example](http://web.archive.org/web/20100816175634/http://blog.henriklarsentoft.com/2010/07/android-tabactivity-nested-activities/)

To make this more easier, [Fragments](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Fragment.html) are introduced. it does the same operation as Activity Group(to replace views). here are few examples,

http://android.codeandmagic.org/2011/07/android-tabs-with-fragments/

http://developer.android.com/resources/samples/Support4Demos/src/com/example/android/supportv4/app/FragmentTabs.html