# Android tab-bar activity

Tags: android, tabbar, android-tabhost, tabwidget

I am using tab-bar activity. And setting three activities in three tabs. When I open a fourth activity it is opening in separate activity and can not see tabs that I set. How can I open a fourth activity which does not hide three tab bars.

Comment: Check this, http://stackoverflow.com/a/11132805/603744

Comment: Try to use the [TabGroupActivity](http://ericharlow.blogspot.in/2010/09/experience-multiple-android-activities.html)

Answer (score 0):

To do this you can use following instead of activity

```
1. View Flipper
2. Fragment Activity
```